# Django forms - object has no attribute error when trying to reference one of the form fields

Tags: python, django

Well this is really confusing to me, whenever I execute the view I get an error at x = form.file_name form has no attribute file_name. However, when I comment out the line x = form.file_name the html {{form.file_name}} does not return an error and a file browser is outputted to the page. How come form.file_name returns an error when executed in views.py but not in upload.html?

upload.html

```
{{form.file_name}}
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
        form = CsvForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        x = form.file_name
        return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', {'form' : form})
```

forms.py

```
class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Csv
        fields = ('file_name', 'public')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Csv(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs', max_length = 100)
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "File id: {}".format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this because behind the scene form saves the bound fields using `__getitem__`.

So to access correctly the bound field:

```
form["file_name"]
```

If you want to access the field:

```
form.fields["file_name"]
```